# gcc error: undefined reference to ***

Tags: c, gcc

In my main .c file, I have defined `NUMBER` as:

```
#define NUMBER '0'
```

In another .c file2, I have declared it as an "extern int" variable and used it. But while compiling gcc gives the following error message:

```
/tmp/ccsIkxdR.o: In function `file2':
file2.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `NUMBER'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please suggest me a way out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

When you use `#define` is defines a macro for the *pre-processor*. This macro will only be visible in the source file you defined it in. No other source file will see this macro definition, and the pre-processor will not be able to expand the macro for you in the other source file so the compiler sees the symbol `NUMBER` and it doesn't have a declaration for any such symbol.

To fix this you have two choices:

1. Put the macro in a header file that you include in both source files.
2. Define `NUMBER` as a proper variable instead of a macro, and then have an `extern` declaration in the other source file.

Comment: Good explanation on why it doesn't work. Any comment on how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

When you `#define` something (i.e create a pre-processor macro) in a C file, it works as text replacement, it's *not* the declaration of a variable. So, when you write `#define NUMBER '0'` and write `extern int NUMBER;` later, the compiler converts it to `extern int '0';` before compilation, which is quite meaningless and erroneous.

If you want to define a constant and access it from elsewhere, you can write:

```
const int NUMBER = '0';
```

and

```
extern int NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `NUMBER` is of type `int`, you could declare it as an enumeration constant:

```
enum { NUMBER = '0' };
```

You'd have to put that in a header file (.h) and include that header in your compilation unit (.c file).